# Changing outputs of Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm stuck on an assignment in which we have to replace every output comming from an array of "yes" with "no", and leave any other output untouched.

I keep getting the error `cannot convert from String to String[]`, and I'm unsure of how to work around this, because I haven't been able to find any `String` to `String[]` conversion in the Javadoc.

I've been trying to find a solution for a while, so I just need a push in the right direction.

```
String[] makeItANegativeArray(String[] inputArray) {
    String x = "no";
    if (inputArray.equals("yes")) {
        return x;
    } else {
        return inputArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do sth like this

```
String [] makeItANegativeArray( String [] inputArray ) 
{
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (inputArray[i].equals("yes"))
    {
        inputArray[i] = "no";
    }
}
return inputArray;
}
```

When you say inputArray.equals it compares array with string and it gives error.You have to iterate through all elements in array and set yes to no and return the edited array.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at the code

```
//Start the function
String[] makeItANegativeArray( String [] inputArray ) {

// function needs    String[] as input
// function suspects String[] as output (or return)

    // initialise the variable x
    String x = "no";

    // if the input array is equal to the string VALUE "yes"
    // (which is WEIRD because it's an ARRAY not a VALUE)
    if (inputArray.equals("yes"))
    {
        //return A VALUE
        //so here we return a VALUE while the function is suspecting an ARRAY
        //this causes the error
        return x;
    }
    else 
    {
        //return an array
        //(hence if this happens, the function terminates at the first iteration)
        return inputArray;
    }
}
```

Clearly, your input is an `array` and your output should be an `array` as well.

Hence you will have to loop over each element of the input array and construct and output array before returning **anything**.

For example:

```
String[] makeItANegativeArray( String[] inputArray ) {

    String x = "yes";
    String y = "no";

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray[i].equals("yes"))
        {
            inputArray[i] = y;
        }
        else 
        {
            inputArray[i] = x;
        }
    }

    return inputArray;
}
```

What this does is turn every "*yes*" in the array into a "*no*" and every "*no*" into a "*yes*".
So it sort of "**inverts**" the array.

*Is this what it is supposed to do?*

**Alternatively,**

If you just want to turn the whole array into an array of only "*no*'s", then do the following:

```
String[] makeItANegativeArray( String[] inputArray ) {

    String x = "no";

    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
    {
        if (inputArray[i].equals("yes"))
        {
            inputArray[i] = x;
        }
    }

    return inputArray;
}
```

Comment: @Dolda2000: Ow I didn't know that. Thanks for informing me :)

Comment: when all the code I insert is simply:
          return input array;
I receive 2 points for the problem... wheras when I invert my array as you suggested, the grading program does not recognize my input to be correct (or doing anything at all)
I don't know why this is, your for loop makes plain sense to me.

Comment: @dylnard: I do not understand your comment. Please rephrase and consider accepting my answer.

Comment: @dylnard: This is plain insanity: your prof. uses a grading **PROGRAM**? How in the world can that grade objectively? This piece of code might be a bit more extended, but it is absolutely correct. Wait let me change it a bit so the program may recognize it's correctness.

Comment: That works great thanks, for some reason no matter what changes I make I still end up with a 3/4 .... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: You are dealing with an array.

`inputArray.equals("yes")` is what causing the error.  You are supposed to get each element in the Array and compare it to "yes".

What the error is telling you is you cannot compare an array of `String` with a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with your `String[] inputArray`. Because you are comparing it's value as if it were a String object, not a String array. If you want to access the first element of the inputArray and then compare the value of that, then that would be within the `makeItNegativeArray(String[])`:

```
String[] outputArray = new String[inputArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
{
    if (inputArray[i].equals("yes"))
    {
        outputArray[i] = "no";
    }
    else 
    {
        outputArray[i] = "yes"
    }
}
return outputArray;
```

I would suggest that you have a look at the use of Arrays in Java and how they differ from single objects. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html as that may give you a real grasp of the usage of arrays and how they can be accessed. Arrays are a really important concept in programming and if you can master it, you will take another step into becoming a star.

Comment: I have no idea as to what the values of my input are as my method simply modifies the grading program while I edit my methods, so I guess I don't really know how to change each individual possible "yes" input and return them as "no" instead without knowing what my input is going to be.

Comment: That's where your for loop comes in to play. It will loop through the array and test to see if each element equals to 'yes' and set the corresponding outputArray element to that same String value (either 'yes', or 'no').